# Audiomanager.abandonAudioFocus doesn't resume playing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to silence audio player while a phrase is spoken by the text-to-speech system. The audiomanager, as expected, reduce the volume when the audio focus is requested but when abandonAudioFocus is called, the volume is not restored and the abandonAudioFocus's callback is not called.
This is my code:

```
private class SpeakRunnable implements Runnable {
    String mText;

    public SpeakRunnable(String text) {
        mText = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        stream_volume = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        am.requestAudioFocus(new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                  //Check if focus granted
                  .....
                  HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                  params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "none");
                  talker.speak(mText, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, params);
            }
        },
        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
        AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);

    }
}
```

and:

```
talker.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStart(String utteranceId) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String utteranceId) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                am.abandonAudioFocus(new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {                     
                    @Override
                    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                        Log.v(app_id, "CALLBACK");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the same `AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener` to `abandonAudioFocus` that you passed to `requestAudioFocus`. This is described in [the documentation for `abandonAudioFocus`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#abandonAudioFocus(android.media.AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener)):

```
public int abandonAudioFocus (AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener l)

Parameters
l   the listener with which focus was requested.
```

Also, I don't think you should expect the `onAudioFocusChange` method in *your* listener to be called as a result of you abandoning audio focus. When you abandon audio focus, *some other* audio focus client that has requested audio focus will be notified that it has gained focus.
If you want to read up on how this is implemented internally in Android you can take a look at the [`MediaFocusControl` source code](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/base/tree/media/java/android/media/MediaFocusControl.java?h=aosp-new/master#n511).